# How do i get information about types from an FSharp prompt

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data

I am working with FSharp and am trying to find out more information about the types i am consuming from the FSharp.Data library. For example, how can i go about find out if HttpMessageBody is a discriminated union etc from the FSharp interactive prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use methods from `Reflection.FSharpType` to gain information:

For example

```
 static member IsUnion : Type * ?BindingFlags -> bool
```

will tell you if a type is a Union type.

More functions in the module are [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370530.aspx)

Comment: Wow. That seems like a pretty obtuse way of getting at the information. I was hoping for something like the python help function. Is there a way to view the type definitions?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a simple way to get the information directly from F# interactive (but, as mentioned by John Palmer, it would not be too hard to write a helper function that gets this information using F# reflection and prints it).

However, if you're using Visual Studio or MonoDevelop (Xamarin Studio), then you should see all the information you need in the tool tip that is displayed when you hover over the type name in the editor or find it in the autocomplete:

[image: Visual Studio showing that HttpResponseBody is a discriminated union]

Comment: The primary usage pattern for fsi is writing the code in VS and sending it to fsi.  Thats why no further work was done on the intellisense and autocompletion features in fsi itself.

Answer (score -1):

I believe [Code Quotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx) is what you are looking for.